# How to pass a parameter(s) to a function where the function is itself a parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, mootools

So, I want to pass paramA and paramB to functionTwo() when calling functionOne(), like so:

```
function functionOne( myFunc )
{
   $aj = new Ajax('hhtp://myurl', {

      method: 'get',
      update: 'myDiv',
      onComplete: myFunc

   }).request();

}

function functionTwo( paramA, paramB )
{
  alert( paramA );
  alert( paramB );
}

// somehow, i want to be able to pass paramA and paramB here:
functionOne( functionTwo );
```

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**Edit**

What if functionOne() and functionTwo() were defined in a class?

ie. this used to work (without parameters):

```
this.functionOne ( this.functionTwo );
```

But this doesn't work (with parameters)

```
this.functionOne (function() { this.functionTwo(paramA, paramB); });
```

Nor something like this:

```
this.functionOne (function() { this.call(functionTwo, paramA, paramB) });
```

ps. js newbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to pass `functionTwo` to `functionOne` with a specified set of parameters.  If so then use the following

```
functionOne (function() { functionTwo(paramA, paramB); });
```

Comment: I'm testing things out. I'll see how I go. thanks for your response

Comment: +1. the search term is 'closure' if you want to learn more about this.

Comment: I suppose this is the answer to my question. But the elusive solution when implemented in a class is still to be found.

Answer (score 2):

Check out func.call() and func.apply() on the Mozilla dev site.  Both allow you to invoke a reference to a function with dynamic args.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: I'm testing things out. I'll see how I go. thanks for your response